# System.Drawing.Image as source for asp.net image container

Tags: asp.net, image, arrays

I created image from byte array

```
System.Drawing.Image newImage;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
{
       ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
       newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);                
}
```

and now I need to have this image as a source for asp:Image (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image). Is this possible as I know that conversion is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
  System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.ContentType = "image/Gif";
  Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());


<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/pic.aspx"/>
```

Comment: Just a heads-up: If session state is enabled, browsers will be able to fetch only one image at a time due to locking issues. See **Concurrent Requests and Session State** here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: Let's say this "saving code" is in Page_Load event of a page pic.aspx. Do I still call the same pic.aspx page as ImageUrl?

Comment: Sorry you have to try that because honestly I have never done that before

Answer (score 1):

### If you're starting with a byte array, just send that. No need to parse and re-encode it unless you need to change the image format.

If you do need to perform image manipulations, you might [consider an existing library](http://imageresizing.net) that [doesn't have memory leaks, and is optimized for the server](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/). GDI calls are dangerous on the server - you have to know exactly what you're doing.

For the best performance, use an HttpModule to answer the request. An aspx page as suggested by MUG4N will add significant overhead to the request. A .ashx would be better than a .aspx file, but wouldn't be MVC compatible, and doesn't permit disk caching as can be accomplished via an HttpModule and a RewritePath call.